# message disappeared

Tags: gmail

I received the mail on Oct 12, I downloaded the attachment. Today I looked for the mail, but it disappeared from all mail, inbox and any other label that I have.
The attachment is where I put it, thanks god.
How can I find it?
Windows 10, gmail.
Thanks, Izzy

Comment: could you have deleted it?

Answer (score 1):

If you received the message on `Oct. 12, 2022` and it has an `attachment` and you have not `permanently deleted` it, the following search will work in HTML Gmail https://mail.google.com/

```
after:2022/10/12 before:2022/10/13 has:attachment in:anywhere
```

Direct URL [Search: Oct 12 12am-11:59pm with attachment in anywhere](https://mail.google.com/#search/after%3A2022%2F10%2F12+before%3A2022%2F10%2F13+has%3Aattachment+in%3Aanywhere)

This translates to:

- **RECEIVED**
  12:00 AM - 11:59 PM, October 12, 2022
- **AND HAS**
  attachment
- **AND IN**
  All Mail **OR** SPAM **OR** Trash

If your message is not returned as part of this search, then at least one of the following **must be true**:

1. Your message has `no attachment` and is being excluded from the search (e.g. maybe it was a link to an attachment in the msg)
2. The message was `not received October 12, 2022`
3. You `permanently deleted` the message.
   Keep in mind that simply deleting the message would still have it show up in the search as deleted messages are kept in the `Trash` folder for 30 days, the `Trash` folder is included in the search above, and the message is `less than 30 days old`.